# Twilio REST API: How to map a Credential List for use by SIP Registration

Tags: twilio

I am using the Twilio rest API (with PHP) to create a SIP domain, enable it for SIP Registration, and then create a Credential List, a Credential and map the Credential List to the SIP Domain.

The Twilio console shows that this is all succeeding, except the Credential List is only mapped for Voice Authentication; it is not also mapped for SIP Registration. See the image of my console.

[SIP Registration Credential List Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAOUX.jpg)

How do I use the API to also map the credential list for SIP Registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update on this 2017 Q&A...the twilio Voice/SIP REST API and the helper libraries now allow you to map credential lists to a SIP domain, for both SIP endpoint registration and for voice authentication.

Here is a fragment showing how to do it in NodeJS:

```
      const cl = await client.sip.credentialLists
        .create({friendlyName: 'MyCredentials'});
      await client.sip.domains(sipDomain.sid).auth.calls.credentialListMappings
        .create({credentialListSid: cl.sid});
      await client.sip.domains(sipDomain.sid).auth.registrations.credentialListMappings
        .create({credentialListSid: cl.sid});
```

You can also delete credentialListMappings using the same API structure, with the remove() method.

Sorry, the fragment is not php but hopefully still useful to the OP and others. I assume the php library is very similar to the NodeJS one in this area. And, of course, you can always drop down and use the REST API for this feature, if necessary. See the REST docs for a description of the 'Auth/Calls' and 'Auth/Registrations' sub-resources.

Note: I did not find this capability in the helper library docs but it's in the twilio (NodeJS) package source code.

Comment: I went back and re-tested this and received the same result as originally posted.
Is your comment based on tested code or only based on reviewing Twilio documents, etc?

Comment: My comment was based on tested (NodeJS) code. When you say that you re-tested I assume you mean you tested code that was changed to be similar to what I showed in my NodeJS sample.

Comment: My re-test was using my existing code since it is the PHP equivalent of what you showed in NodeJS. Twilio's docs haven't changed in terms of the code they show for how to register a credential. 
When I asked if you "tested" what I meant was, have you successfully registered a SIP endpoint device using the username and password you installed using your code?

Comment: Yes, I tested my code and it works. Perhaps you could post the code that is not working?

Comment: Thanks @JLafer - I've dug into the further with Sean from Twilio support and I now have it working.

Comment: PHP Code that I needed to add to my existing code:

`$credentialRegistrations = $client->sip->domains($domainSid)->auth->registrations->credentialListMappings->create($credentialListSid);`

Answer (score 0):

Twilio has responded to my support inquiry on this and reported that the functionality does not yet exist. Quoting part of there answer here:

> There is currently no Twilio API that will allow you to associate a CredentialList with a SIP Domain for the purposes of SIP Registration. The currently available CredentialListMapping API only associates a CredentialList with a SIP Domain for the purpose of authenticating calls not registrations.

So this means it is currently not possible to use the API to create a fully functional SIP voice service.

Comment: Based on the API update mentioned on version 5.21.0 I have asked Twilio support for an update and am awaiting their reply.
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/CHANGES.md#2018-08-03-version-5210